# Issue tracker implemented in Microsoft Dynamics AX or standalone

Tags: issue-tracker

We're introducing a new ERP, Microsoft Dynamics AX.

The guy responsible for the introduction/maintenance of the ERP wants to include the issue tracker (which I intend to use for service requests of our customers as well as internal stuff like bugs/features we discovered ourselves).

I'm not exactly sure but it doesn't feel like a good thing to do.

So here's the question:

Is there a good issue tracker/bug tracker/ticket system to use in conjuction with Microsoft Dynamics AX, so data can be shared easily (like the amount of time spent on a single ticket or to get a list of customers from the ERP)?

It would be also of great help to hear what you are using (e.g. a standalone system or intergrated as part of an ERP)?